# Have Checkbox checked by default in UI

Tags: checkbox, wix

I am trying to add a new checkbox into a UI screen for my installer.

So far I have declared the property as seen below:

```
<Property Id="RS232" Value="1" Secure="yes"/>
```

And in the UI, my checkbox has been added as:

```
<Control Id="myNewCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" X="200" Y="170" Text="Generic Driver" Width="130" Height="15" Property="RS232" CheckBoxValue="1"/>
```

From documentation I have read I am lead to believe that as long as CheckBoxValue and Value are equal i.e 1 in this case, then the checkbox should be checked by default.

There are already existing checkboxes on this same UI and this is true for them, so I do not understand why in my additional case, the checkbox is not active.

Another note to be made is that when I go through the installation process to test the new checkbox, the dialog disappears when I hover over it with a mouse and I am unable to check/uncheck the box.

I first thought that perhaps the Width field for the text was not big enough, but I have tested by expanding this with no results.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check whether the control overlaps with another. (I mean two controls in the same position). This may be the reason why your check box is not active.

Comment: Hi Leon, The XY coordinates were previously blank so its not an overlap issue (I had already made that mistake).  I ran the code again today and the checkbox has appeared checked (i'm not sure why) The only remaining issue is the fact that I can't actually uncheck it properly without the text blanking out..

Comment: Hi Leon, I checked through my code again and you were right about an overlap. I had originally copy/pasted an existing checkbox and forgot to change the XY coordinates, which is the kind of mistake I thought you were referring to. When I checked through the code more thoroughly I noticed that the checkbox that was to the left of the one I had added had double the width value and so was overlapping. Thanks for the info!